# Is there a way to check if the transactions are happening on binance smart chain network or ethereum smart chain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, dapps, smart-contract-wallets

I'm new to block chain development and developing a DApp on binance smart chain. In my DApp, I changed the network provider from default ethereum web provider to binance test network provider. DApp is working fine but I want the affirmation that my transactions are happening on binance test network. Is there a way to check if the transaction is happening on binance smart chain network or ethereum network? Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. When you submit a transaction, you obtain a transaction hash.

You can check if your transaction hash is really on the binance test chain with their web page explorer: https://testnet.bscscan.com/

But as a side note, if you configured your code to work on a specific provider, there is no reason for your transactions to be on another chain (unless you made a mistake or there is a huge bug in the SDK, which would already be fixed considering its nature.)